# How do threads with semaphores run concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

lets say we have

P1
wait(mut)
signal(mut2)
wait(mut3)
signal(mut)

P2
wait(mut)
signal(mut2)
signal(mut)
wait(mut3)

P3
wait(mut)
signal(mut3)
signal(mut2)
wait(mut2)

say we have 3 concurrent threads that are synchronized, does that mean that threads run one after another? and what happens if P3 sends the signal for P2 to continue? Does P2 run after P3 pauses or finishes?

Comment: There is no guarantee of who will obtain a *particular* mutex first any thread could win `wait(mut)` at the start - the first thread who wins it makes the other threads wait. I would start by drawing out a tree of who *can* run, when. It might help to label each sequence point (e.g. P3/2 would refer to `signal(mut3)`).

Comment: For instance, it is not the case that *both* P1/3 and P2/4 can complete before P3/2 as one must wait on the mut3 signal.

Comment: so they don't run concurrently? i also asked whether the other threads start when p1 pauses, or they only start after the whole process finishes.

Comment: *Any* of the threads can run `wait(mut)` first - conceptually they *are all running* but we don't know who is the "winner" of the mutex. An ordering can *only* be established when a thread must actually *wait* for a mutex to be signaled. Then we can say, that, for example, that the ordering (across all threads) must be `wait(m)->signal(m)->wait(m)`.

Comment: ok so the next process only runs when the first pauses or finish its process, am i right?

Comment: The threads are always "running". They must merely wait for the appropriate semaphore to be available before they can continue - this is what allows the establishment that a semaphore/lock must be signaled/released before the execution that requires it can move ahead. Other than that, there are no strict guarantees - any one of the threads may win the first `wait(mut)` so there is no ordering established yet (excepting that at most one can immediately continue).

Comment: if all of the threads are running as opposed to executing, does that mean that a process can never be blocked if there is an even number of wait and signal calls for any semaphore?

Comment: The number of wait/signals can't be relied upon. Here is a simple deadlock: `P1 -> W(A) W(B) S(A) S(B)`, `P2 -> W(B) W(A) S(A) S(B)`. It should be easy to see that a `W(A) W(B) W(B) W(A) S(A) S(B) ..` schedule would cause a deadlock.